# Horizontal Progress Bar Not Working in Asynctask Android For Download file?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progress-bar

I am trying to display horizontal progress bar using `Asynctask` but it is not working for me. It is not display percent progress amount.

here i put my xml and activity file and screen shot file.

[image]

> layout xml

```
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:id="@+id/progresslayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imagepeakmedia"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/peakmedialogo" 
            android:layout_marginTop="100sp"
             />



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imagepeakmedia"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textSize="25sp"
           android:text="" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textpercentage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imagepeakmedia"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
            android:text="%" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"

             />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

> TestActivity.java

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {


    ProgressDialog progressdialog;

    RelativeLayout progresslayout;
    ProgressBar progressbar;
    TextView textprogressbar;
    TextView textpercentage;
    TextView textdownload;

    boolean progress=true;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_progress);

            progressbar=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
            textprogressbar=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
            textpercentage=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textpercentage);
            textdownload=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textdownload);

             new FirstDownloadFileFromURL().execute("http://pr83.webofficeserver.info/img/thumbnails/video/iPhone5.mp4");

    }

    public class FirstDownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> 
    {

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() 
        {
            // some work
        }


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) 
        {

            try 
            {   

                BufferedOutputStream out = null;

                String originalurl=f_url[0];
                Uri cu = Uri.parse(originalurl);
                File f2= new File("" + cu);
                String  filename=f2.getName();

                Log.i("DownloadFile", "DownloadURL:" +originalurl.replaceAll(" ", "%20"));
                Log.i("DownloadFile", "filename: " + filename);

                String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
                new File(root + "/montorwerbung").mkdirs();

                File SmartAR = new File(root + "/montorwerbung", "");
                SmartAR.mkdirs();
                File outputFile = new File(SmartAR, filename);
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
                String url1 = originalurl;
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url1)
                .openConnection();
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.connect();
                int lenghtOfFile = conn.getContentLength();
                final InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream(), 1024); // buffer size
                // 1KB
                out = new BufferedOutputStream(fos, 1024);
                int b;
                int a=0;
                long total = 0;
                while ((b = in.read()) != -1) 
                {   
                    total += b;
                            publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));

                        out.write(b);
                }
                out.close();
                conn.disconnect();

            } catch (final MalformedURLException e) {
                showError("Error : MalformedURLException " + e);        
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (final IOException e) {
                showError("Error : IOException " + e);          
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (final Exception e) {
                showError("Error : Please Check Your Wifi connection " + e);
            }       
            return null;
        }


         @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
         Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC",progress[0]);
         progressbar.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
    }

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) 
        {

            // some work

        }
    }  


    public void showError(final String err)
     {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
            {
                public void run() 
                {

                }

            });
     }


}
```

Comment: never ever update any UI in the `doInBackground()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to implement `onProgressUpdate(....)` for that.

```
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
         Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC",progress[0]);
         mProgressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
    }
```

and used it in your `doInBackground(..)` by calling `publishProgress(...)` like so.

```
while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
total += count;
publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));
output.write(data, 0, count);
}
```

Comment: but i was not used progressdiaog i used progressbar

Comment: @AndroidTech change with progress bar

Comment: @AndroidTech why you display progress in your `TextView`? implement `Progress dialog` and set style as `STYLE_HORIZONTAL` it'll display progress

Comment: i want to create custome design because it is in requirement

Comment: @AndroidTech if you really gonna do this then i have another way. Create a separate `Thread` and do this stuff on it and create one `Handler` that'll update your `ProressBar` and display Progress in your `TextView`.

Comment: actually i have morethan 50 files for download and can we use single progress bar for multiple files download and display 100% done when all file is download

Comment: hey why progressbar is not stop is going on like 100 101 102 is not stop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55050/discussion-between-android-tech-and-simple-plan).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update views from background thread, only UI thread can touch views. Actually it is weird that you have not got an Exception. In order to update views from background thread you may use either [Activity.runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) method or [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) class. But keep in mind that Handler should be created in UI thread in order to work with it

Answer (score 0):

This is not automatic, AsyncTask have a [onProgressUpdate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate%28Progress...%29) method you have to implements

Here you have to update your ProgressBar

Then you have to call `publishProgress` to invoke that method and you're done

See the example at the [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) doc :

```
 private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
 protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
     int count = urls.length;
     long totalSize = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
         totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
         publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
         // Escape early if cancel() is called
         if (isCancelled()) break;
     }
     return totalSize;
 }

 protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
     setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
 }

 protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
     showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
 }
}
```

Here they use their `setProgressPercent()` to update whatever they want (so your ProgressBar)